# Corret file structure for project in deta (python.app)

Tags: python, project

I have a local folder called NinMusX in my Mac Desktop:

NinMusX/Spacefile

NinMusX/src/custom
NinMusX/src/custom/go.mod
NinMusX/src/custom/main
NinMusX/src/GetAlbum.py

i would like to push to deta the GetAlbum.py

the project was correctly created on the site thanks to command space new

Now i am trying to push it space push, but i get this error:

Validating your Spacefile...

Your Spacefile looks good, proceeding with your push!

✓ Successfully started your build!
✓ Successfully pushed your Spacefile!

Pushing your code (3 files) & running build process...

2023/08/10 11:29:38
2023/08/10 11:29:38 Parsing Spacefile...
2023/08/10 11:29:39 Scanned micros:
2023/08/10 11:29:39 └ python-app
2023/08/10 11:29:39 └ custom-app
2023/08/10 11:29:39
2023/08/10 11:29:39 Building micro python-app...
2023/08/10 11:29:39 [python-app] lstat /tmp/task/read/NinMusX/src/GetAlbum.py: no such file or directory

Spacefile:

```
v: 0
micros:
  - name: python-app
    src: ./NinMusX/src
    engine: python3.9
    primary: true

  - name: custom-app
    src: ./src/custom
    engine: custom
    commands:
      - go get
      - go build main
    run: ./main
    include:
      - main
```

go.mod file

```
module NinMusX

go 1.20
```

could you please suggest me the corrections to the structure, or how to properly edit files?

Thank you